# display a input filed when user selects other for title in a select pull down list

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

What is the best way to display a text filed when the user selects other in a title select pull down menu

The code i have got at the moment is:

```
<%= f.input :parenttitle, label: "Your Title", as: :select, collection:  [["Miss","Miss"],["Mr","Mr"],["Mrs","Mrs"], ["Ms","Ms"],["Other","Other"],["Dr","Dr"]], :include_blank => "-Select one-"  %>
<%= f.input :parenttitle, label: false,  input_html: {  id: "parenttitle_other", value: "" }%>
```

i am using the following js code to initally hide the field and then display it when the user selects other

```
$("#parenttitle_other").hide()

$("#saolf_parenttitle").change(function() { 
    if ($("#saolf_parenttitle").val()=="Other") 
        $("#parenttitle_other").show(); 
    else $("#parenttitle_other").hide(); 
});
```

I have used the same variable for both the select and input field.

Is their a better way to code this just using ruby/rails and would it be better to to you another variable for the other field and at the model level add it to the original field if other is selected?

Comment: I would think that it is better to use a different variable and merge them in the backend. However, I am curious to know if your current code works as expected?

Comment: I Agree - maybe do f.input :parenttitle_other as the second input, and merge the params in the controller after it's posted.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using the same name for inputs, or only the last will be used. So, if you have selected something from your select box and your input box is blank just after, `params[:parenttitle]` will still be `''`.

You can named the second `parenttitle_other` and do something like this in your controller :

```
parent_title = params[:parenttitle] == 'other' ? params[:parentitle_other] : params[:parenttitle]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are all right i had to use a second variable and in the controller create and update methods i put the following code

```
if params[:saolf][:parenttitle] == 'Other' 
  params[:saolf][:parenttitle] = params[:saolf][:parenttitleother]
end
```

I still think there may be a better and more ruby/rails ways where i could easily add a pull down select title field and when the user selects "Other" it automatically displays a text field and allows you to enter a value thru it.

Once you start to code in ruby/rails you always learn better ways to do things and all in one line